# LOAD DATA #2027 Malformed Packet

Tags: mysql, sql

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'home/magazinb/public_html/stoc.csv'
 INTO TABLE stock
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 IGNORE 1 LINES
```

I am using this `sql` query with `MariaDB`. site is on shared hosting.
It gives me this error `#2027 - Malformed packet`
I've tried all the things i could that i found.

Comment: Why you use `LOCAL` when the file to be loaded is already local?

Comment: it gives me another error : #1045 - Access denied for user 'magazinb'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Solve this error - it is a root of the problem.

Comment: but how i m running this in phpmyadmin directly